# How to fetch image from api

Tags: jquery, json, node.js, api

I got the image name  in pic variable , but now i'm blank how to show that image in front end .

```
<script>
$.getJSON(`https://openlibrary.org/authors/<%= match %>.json`, function(data) {


    var text = `<tr><td>${data.name}</td>
                    <td>${data.bio}</td>
                    <td>${data.alternate_names}</td>
                <td>${data.birth_date}</td></tr>`
    var pic = `${data.photos}`
    $(".mypanel").html(text);
    $(".picpanel").html(pic);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your complete solution

```
   <script>
          $.getJSON(`https://openlibrary.org/authors/<%= match %>.json`, function(data) {


    var text = `<tr><td>${data.name}</td>
                    <td>${data.bio}</td>
                    <td>${data.alternate_names}</td>
                <td>${data.birth_date}</td></tr>`
    var pic = `${data.photos[0]}`
    $(".mypanel").html(text);
    var add =pic+'-M.jpg'
    console.log(add);
    $(".picpanel").append("<img src='https://covers.openlibrary.org/a/id/" + add + "'>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways, you can simply implement them in img tags :

```
$(".picpanel").append("<img src='" + pic + "'>");
```

you can also implement it on a element as background :

```
$(".picpanel").css('background-image', 'url(' + pic + ')');
```

Edit:
wanted solution :

```
<script>
$.getJSON(`https://openlibrary.org/authors/<%= match %>.json`, function(data) {


    var text = `<tr><td>${data.name}</td>
                <td>${data.bio}</td>
                <td>${data.alternate_names}</td>
            <td>${data.birth_date}</td></tr>`
    var pic = data.photos;
    $(".mypanel").html(text);
    if(pic!==undefined && pic.length>0){
        $(".picpanel").html("<img src='//covers.openlibrary.org/a/id/" + pic[0] + "-M.jpg'>");
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: i'm having its name , like pic = black , not black.jpeg

Comment: You get a picture as just a name? Without path or data, that's going to be pretty hard to show if you don't have locally already.

Comment: it seems that the id you are getting from the json file is mapped to this image url : http://covers.openlibrary.org/a/id/*heretheimageurl*-M.jpg

Comment: This is the api link , now i want image from this  api https://openlibrary.org/authors/OL54736A.json

Comment: it would look like this : http://covers.openlibrary.org/a/id/6458674-M.jpg (6458674) is the first photo id

Answer (score 0):

In regard to your current context, it would be like this, I guess.

```
$(".picpanel").html("<img src='" + pic + "' />");
```